# What is the maximum number of transactions per seconds on Bitcoin Cash?

Tags: scalability, performance, bitcoin-cash

What is the maximum number of transactions per seconds on Bitcoin Cash? I know that on Bitcoin (BTC) is was 7 tx/s.

Comment: Also relevant: See [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/59408/with-100-segwit-transactions-what-would-be-the-max-number-of-transaction-confi) for an interesting analysis of the maximum number of transactions BTC can support with segwit (the estimate given is ~20/sec) and [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/71346/whats-the-difference-between-btc-and-bch-transaction-capacity/71480#71480) for a comparison of average BTC transaction capacity to BCH transaction capacity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The throughput in Bitcoin is not defined in transactions per second, rather indirectly, via block size limit. What matters in the size of transactions in bytes. The more complex the transaction is (complex meaning more inputs and outputs, long scripts), the more space it takes. A typical full (nearly 1 MB) block in Bitcoin includes around 2000 transactions, or around 3 tx / sec at 10 min / block. 7 tx / sec in the absolute maximum, calculated in the assumption that a transaction contains one input and one output (most real-world transactions contain two outputs -- the second one being the change). BCC increases the block size limit to 8 MB, that means it can handle 8 times more (assuming other things equal).

Comment: Can this at all be considered a usable transaction network for handling global scale transactions then?

Comment: @wv12 depends on your requirements... Bitcoin Cash mining is (was?) unstable in terms of difficulty. Sometimes blocks come often, sometimes only once every hour or so...  You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@jimmysong/bitcoin-cash-difficulty-adjustments-2ec589099a8e).

Comment: So you're saying ("8 times more") that if BTC can roughly handle a theoretical maximum of 7 transactions/sec., then BCH can handle 56?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't been following BCH since, they may have implemented something else to increase the throughput.